# Dialog offset from bottom to status bar height

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-custom-view

I've copied the source code of `BottomSheetDialog` and `BottomSheetBehavior` and made a `SideSheetDialog` and `SideSheetBehavior` the dialog works as expected and except that the dialog is offset from the bottom to about the height of status bar. When i removed `fitsSystemWindows="false"` it stretched to the entire screen in height (below the status bar and below the soft navigation bar). I just want the dialog to fit in between the status bar and the soft navigation bar

[image: Here is the ScreenShot]

The full source code is hosted in [github](https://github.com/sonyraj/SideSheetDemo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed fitSystemWindows=true to false and it works as expected